# Remote Development with NSight 6.5 with "indirect" ssh

Tags: eclipse, gpgpu, nvidia, nsight

Suppose I can log in to a gpu sever named `gpu1.sp.sw`, and there are `gpu2.sp.sw` and `gpu3.sp.sw` to which I cannot log in directly but can be reached by `ssh gpu-2`, `ssh gpu-3`, after I am already on `gpu1.sp.sw`.

**My question** is: If I want NSight 6.5 to run and debug remotely on gpu-2 or gpu-3, how can I do it?

Comment: While kludgy, ssh-tunnels or [`ProxyCommand`](http://askubuntu.com/a/311454/30881) can be a viable workaround.

Comment: @aland, could you elaborate on any of those? Any viable workaround could be an answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

As workaround you can use ssh tunnels: run something like

```
ssh gpu1.sp.sw -L2202:gpu2.sp.sw:22 -L2345:gpu2.sp.sw:2345 -nNT
```

in background console. Then configure NSight remote debugging to connect to server `localhost`, ssh port 2202 and cuda-gdbserver port 2345.